# "Cast to number failed for value ... at path ... " Error when using updateOne with $pop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having this error and I'm not sure if this is an error in my query or how I set up the schema for this document. I can insert without problem though, to this document in the db. Now I'm trying to remove an element in cartItems field but can't do so.

Here is the error:

```
CastError: Cast to number failed for value "613997c799907eadff60cff1" (type string) at path "cartItems"
```

I set up my schema like this. And as much as possible I'd like it to stay that way because all of my other codes might get affected and I don't want that at the moment.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

cartItems:{
    
    type: Array
}})
```

Then here is the code that updates the db:

```
module.exports.removeFromCart = (userId,productId)=>{

                                                        
return User.updateOne({_id: userId}, {$pop: {cartItems:{item:productId}}}).then((result)=>{

    console.log(result);


}).catch(error=>{

    //THIS THROWS THE ERROR I"M GETTING
    console.log(error);
})}
```

What could I be doing wrong here? By the way, I can console.log all the data being passed to the query so I'm sure I'm not passing undefined data to mongoose query.

Answer (score 1):

The `$pop` operator expects a number (1 or -1) after `cartItems:`, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/).

To remove an element based on a filter, use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

Comment: Oh, I checked the documentation and all the examples are just popping first or last element in array. Now I'm not sure if pop is the right function to use with my scenario, I'd just like to remove one instance of the element, using my filter. Can I still do it with pop? Like just removing the first element that matches my filter